# Why doesn´t it work the other way arround? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so I have this command:

```
SELECT t.Character_ID, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM characters t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Now my table has an extra rows with the number starting from 1. Next I extend the command with a WHERE command and everything works fine:

```
SELECT t.Character_ID, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM characters t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE @rownum < 5
```

And now I would like to extend the command as follows:

```
SELECT t.Character_ID, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM characters t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE @rownum > 5
```

or

```
SELECT t.Character_ID, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM characters t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE @rownum BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
```

And this doesnt work and i dont know why. I doesn´t get an error or something but I got nothing as a return just an empty table. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: No i doesnt get an error i get nothing xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use your query as a subquery and then filter:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT t.Character_ID, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM characters t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
) t
WHERE t.rank > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In the order of operations the where comes before the select - so your first query works but the other 2 don't. fix by wrapping in main query where you can test row number, search for sql order of operations for articles on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `offset/limit`:

```
SELECT t.Character_ID, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM characters t CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 99999999;
```

Another method uses a `having` clause:

```
SELECT t.Character_ID, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM characters t CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
HAVING rank > 5;
```

No subquery is needed.

Two more things.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so `ORDER BY` is almost always used in such a query.  Second, you should also know that variables assignments in `SELECT` statements are deprecated.  You should learn to use window functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Waaal . . . In general in MySQL, you want to avoid subqueries, because the optimizer has the nasty habit of materializing them (it is getting better, but still).